# How can I use one program for graphics and one program for processing?

Tags: python, vpython

What I'm doing is creating a model of a football field, which has a lot of code simply because there are a lot of parts to a football field. This code is more than 300 lines long. This is quite annoying to scroll through, and I don't want to put it at the end of my code since I might have to go back and edit it, which brings back the scroll program. The rest of this program will be processing sets of coordinates on the field and creating movement animations. Is there any way I can split this into two separate files, one that is just the graphic side and the other that is the processing side?

Comment: Yes, you can split it into as many files as you want, as separate modules that you import.

Comment: See https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages or similar of your choice,

Answer (score 0):

Yup!

1. Put code you want to seperate into new graphics.py file (functions, class, etc)
2. Add import to top of your main file (from graphics import graphics_object)
3. Run it, and if your imports and separation were right, it should run the same.

See also:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp